# Processing Info.plist times out on CI

Tags: ios, fastlane

Little backstory, we are using GitLab CI with Fastlane and for some weeks, we had problems with our certificates, so we disabled the fastlane match / gym lane. Now that our certificates work I wanted to try it, but we get an infinite `Processing Info.plist`. Our CI will time out after 1h.

We have our Info.plist file inside the project folder and under Build Settings and `Info.plist File` we have the correct file and path. `Generate Info.plist File` is set to `No`. Locally building the app works. I just can't get it to work on the CI.

Other teams in the company don't have that problem.

What can I do or what information would you need to help me here?